# Вывод изображений при помощи плагина ACF Photo Gallery Field (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

У каждой записи должна быть возможность добавлять галерею из картинок. Нашла как вариант плагин ACF Photo Gallery Field, вывожу вот таким образом, однако тег img выводит пустой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я допускаю ошибку или возможно есть лучший способ реализовать подгрузку нескольких изображений

```php
<div class="presentation-grid">
    <?php if(have_posts()){ while (have_posts()) {the_post(); ?>
        <?php $images = acf_photo_gallery('gallery', $post->ID); if(count($images)): ?>
        <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } /* конец while */?>
    <?php } /* конец if */?>
</div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите, что у вас там в массиве: **echo '<pre>'; print_r($images); echo '</pre>';**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="presentation-grid">
    <?php if(have_posts()){ while (have_posts()) {the_post(); ?>
        <?php $images = acf_photo_gallery('gallery', $post->ID); if(count($images)): ?>
        <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['full_image_url']; ?>">
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php } /* конец while */?>
    <?php } /* конец if */?>
</div>
```

Ссылка на полноразмерное изображение доступна по ключу **full_image_url**